# Android Volley unable to get data in response

Tags: java, php, android, android-volley

I am trying to make a web-service call using volley and printing the response in the logcat. But I don't know why I am not getting response. Not even any error message.
Below is my code. I know I am missing something. Please correct me.

```
    private void syncData() {
    mProgressDialog.showProgressDialog("Initializing Please Wait...");
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(SalesDashboard.this);
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, SYNC_DATA_SALES, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            mProgressDialog.dismissProgressDialog();
            Log.e("TAG", response);
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            mProgressDialog.dismissProgressDialog();
            Log.e("TAG", error.toString());

        }
    }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap<String , String> params = new HashMap<>();
            String userrole = mSessionManagement.getLoggedInUser().get(SESSION_USER_ROLE);
            params.put("branch", mSessionManagement.getSelectedBranch());
            params.put("staff_id", mSessionManagement.getLoggedInUser().get(SESSION_EMP_ID));
            params.put("user_role", mSessionManagement.getLoggedInUser().get(SESSION_USER_ROLE));
            params.put("user_dept", mSessionManagement.getLoggedInUser().get(SESSION_DEPT_IDS));
            params.put("principal", mSessionManagement.getLoggedInUser().get(SESSION_PRINC_IDS));
            if (userrole.equals(ADMIN) || userrole.equals(COUNTRY_MANAGER)) {
                params.put("user_div", mSessionManagement.getSelectedDivision());
            } else {
                params.put("user_div", mSessionManagement.getLoggedInUser().get(SESSION_DIV_IDS));
            }
            return super.getParams();
        }
    };
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

I am not receiving any error message also or any kind of exception. I have checked the webservice by hitting it on browser the response is displayed correctly on the browser but not able to fetch it in android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you call `super.getParams()` on return instead `params`? Maybe it turn wrong on your request. Then try as follow

```
@Override
protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
    ...
    return params;
}
```

Bonus: use `getMessage` instead do `toString()` your `error` object

Answer (score 0):

Print the stringRequest and check the url and cross verify with ur url

Before that check have u added Internet permissions in manifest file.